# Writing an extra column WITH header

Tags: python, csv

at the moment I have this:

2 variables:
varHeader: ExtraColumn
varContent: ToBeFilledIn

```
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in reader:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

And that all works fine. Problem is that I have 2 variables, varHeader and varContent. And what am I failing at:

1. before writer.writeheader, I need to add an extra column with as title ExtraColumn, which is the content of the varHeader variable.
2. each 'line' needs to add the value of varContent to the newly created column

Although this seemed simple to me, it is blowing my mind, I can't get it done. Guess it's a typical friday disease ;-)

Thanks mates,

regard from a newbie.

Comment: Please show more code. Where is `writer` created?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

with open ...:
    reader = DictReader(in_f)
    writer = DictWriter(out_f, ['ExtraColumn'] + reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in reader:
        line['ExtraColumn'] = varContent
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Yes, that's working, have a nice weekend, you deserved it. What a quick and correct answer !